# Change color of a word in .tex code (TeXstudio)

Tags: texstudio, sourcecode

I would like to change the color/highlight the background of a certain word in the source code of a .tex file in Latex (TeXstudio). This is for editing purposes, and I don't want it to output to the PDF, I just want to change the color of a word or group of words in the code/text. My goal is to be able to quickly see parts of the text that I need to change (ie. that are highlighted). Automatically, some words are already colored in the syntax (\section is blue, \commands are pink...). For example, when you write \textit it automatically changes to pink.

If I add the command \tochange{}, \tochange will turn pink, but can I also change the color/highlight what is in the brackets when this specific command is used? Is this possible? Or is there an easier way?

For example, in a .tex file

[image]

Any ideas? Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! I think I can't understand your demand. Do you want to highlight the word you are writing and un-highlight the previous word when you are writing the next word?

Comment: I updated my question, hopefully it is clearer. I don't want to highlight a word I am writing, just any word in the text. Using a command or some other way.